Is Using a Single Generic Repository for All Entities a Good Practice in Spring Data JPA for Large Project
I’m working on a large Spring Boot application and I’m looking for advice on how to handle repositories for multiple entities. I want to avoid creating individual repositories for each entity and instead use a single, generic repository that can handle CRUD operations and custom queries for all entities dynamically.
Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:
CRUD operations should work for any entity.

Custom queries (e.g., searching by a field like email) may work on user entity

I’m currently using JpaRepository for the implementation.

My question is:
Is it a good practice to use a single generic repository for all entities, especially in a large project?

Are there any potential downsides or limitations to this approach?

Should I stick to individual repositories for each entity for better maintainability and scalability?

Do I need to add anything to this Spring folder structure?

Any code examples, insights, or best practices would be greatly appreciated!
``
@Service
public class LoginService {
    public boolean validateLogin(Map<String, String> credentials){

        return true;
    }
}

I need to check over multiple entities like users, branch, ect... so i need to create each repository for the project.
